# Validate Input in window as a function

Tags: pysimplegui

i'm creating an app with two windows based on Demopograms, but when i try to validate the input in windows def as function method, came this error:

> You cannot Update element with key = - until the window.read() is
> called or finalized

i use this valide cod:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def select(element):
    element.Widget.select_range(0, 'end')
    element.Widget.icursor('end')

def validate(text):
    result = re.match(regex, text)
    return False if result is None or result.group() != text else True

regex = "^[+-]?([0-5](\.(\d{0,2}))?)?$"
old = {'IN1':'0.00', 'IN2':'0.00'}
validate_inputs = ('IN1', 'IN2')


def make_window1():
    layout = [[ sg.Text('Window 1'),],
              [sg.Input(enable_events=True, k='-IN1-')],
              [sg.Text(size=(20,1), k='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Button('Launch 2'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    return sg.Window('Window 1', layout, finalize=True)


def make_window2():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 2')],
    [sg.Input(enable_events=True, k='-IN2-')],
              [sg.Button('Exit')]]

    return sg.Window('Window 2', layout, finalize=True)


def main():
    window1, window2 = make_window1(), None
    while True:
        window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
        for key in validate_inputs:
            window[key].bind('<FocusIn>',  ' IN')
            window[key].bind('<FocusOut>', ' OUT')
        if window == window1 and event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
        # Window 1 stuff
        if event == '-IN-':
            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(values['-IN-'])
        elif event in validate_inputs:
            element, text = window[event], values[event]
            if validate(text):
                try:
                    v = float(text)
                    if v > 5:
                        element.update(old[event])
                        continue
                except ValueError as e:
                    pass
                old[event] = text
            else:
                element.update(old[event])
        elif event.endswith(' IN'):
            key = event.split()[0]
            element, text = window[key], values[key]
            select(element)
        elif event.endswith(' OUT'):
            key = event.split()[0]
            element, text = window[key], values[key]
            try:
                v = float(text)
                element.update(f'{v:.2f}')
            except ValueError as e:
                element.update('0.00')
        elif event == 'Launch 2' and not window2:
            window2 = make_window2()

        # Window 2 stuff
        if window == window2 and event in(sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            window2.close()
            window2 = None

    window1.close()
    if window2 is not None:
        window2.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Only works if i declare the windows without def method. Any solutions?

Comment: Before window finalized, the window is just the architecture of PySimpleGUI, not in GUI, so you cannot do anything about the GUI. Try to add one more option `finalize=True` in `Window`, then the GUI will be finalized. `window.read()` will finalize the window if this window not yet been generated to GUI.

Comment: Still the same: 
"warnings.warn('You cannot Update element with key = {} until the window.read() is called or finalized=True when creating window'.format(self.Key), UserWarning)"

Comment: `calculate_area_window = sg.Window("Calculate Circle Area", calculate_area_layout, modal=True, finalize=True)`

Comment: I already write "finalize =True" and take me this error:

Problem finding your key, and:

The PysimpleGui internal reporting funcion is _widged_was_creatd

Then, the error describes the key letter by letter.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean, can you update your issue with full information, like what your executable script, your script is not executable now, with full exception information.

Comment: @JasonYang, Sorry, i try to use your invalidate code in Two different windows but didnt' work when i a put the windows in def method. How can i do it? Work perfectly when the main windows is not in def method or just one windows. Update de queston. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues about the programming logic in your script.

- Wrong key of elements defined, '-IN1-', 'IN1' or '-IN-' ? '-IN2-' or 'IN2' ?

```py
#L13 old = {'IN1':'0.00', 'IN2':'0.00'}
#L14 validate_inputs = ('IN1', 'IN2')
#L19 [sg.Input(enable_events=True, k='-IN1-')],
#L28 [sg.Input(enable_events=True, k='-IN2-')],
#L44        if event == '-IN-':
```

- Binding only after GUI finalized, or binding in `make_window` function before you return the `window`, not necessary when each event. Both of keys in `validate_inputs` maybe not exist in `window` at the same time.

```py
    window1, window2 = make_window1(), None
    while True:
        window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
        for key in validate_inputs:
            window[key].bind('<FocusIn>',  ' IN')
            window[key].bind('<FocusOut>', ' OUT')
```

maybe you can do it like this

```py
def binding(window):
    for key, element in window.key_dict.items():
        if isinstance(key, tuple) and key[0]=='-IN-':
            window[key].bind('<FocusIn>',  'IN')
            window[key].bind('<FocusOut>', 'OUT')

def make_window1():
    layout = [[ sg.Text('Window 1'),],
              [sg.Input(enable_events=True, k=('-IN-', 1))],
              [sg.Text(size=(20,1), k='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Button('Launch 2'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    window = sg.Window('Window 1', layout, finalize=True)
    binding(window)
    return window
```

- Maybe more issues not founded and not listed here.